# Running a script with assets inside automator application

Tags: macos, automator, bash

So, I'm trying to write an automator application that runs a simple script.

```
python Contents/main.py
```

where `Contents` is the contents of the `.app`.

When the script is run it is run in `~` not in the working directory (wherever the file is placed on a system).

Is there a way to do this?

Note: I am not taking any input to the application, you just double click it.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the path to Your executable from `ps` command. You need to know Your app name. Here's my code with **EchoPath.app** made in *Automator*:

```
DIR=`ps x | grep EchoPath | grep -v grep | cut -c 28- `
```

Sample output:

```
/Users/slozo/Desktop/EchoPath.app/Contents/MacOS/Application Stub
```

`Application Stub` is the default name of the executable created in *Automator*. Knowing this path You can get the path to `Contents` dir with `dirname` command.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - changed the name and it returns nothing

Comment: What is in the file if You do this:
`echo ${DIR} > ~/Desktop/path.txt` after the command I pasted? My `path.txt` contains correct path.

Comment: I figured it out, it doesn't work when debugging in Automator, but works when the application is run normally.